# Kotlin- Generic functions

Tags: swing, generics, kotlin

I am currently trying to write a dsl that allows building Swing user interfaces easily. In order to achieve that and not having to support all types of components i wanted to make a generic function to add a container, which in my case means everything that extends `JPanel`.

What i ended up with was this:

```
fun <T : JPanel> container(containerComponent: T = JPanel(), constraints: LC = LC(), setup: T.() -> Unit): T {
    containerComponent.setup()
    containerComponent.layout = MigLayout(constraints)
    return containerComponent
}
```

However, on line one, at the first parameter, i get an error `Type mismatch: Required T, but found JPanel`, but i don't really understand why, since i specified that T will be something that extends `JPanel`.

Comment: Because it might be a particular subclass that's not satisfied by `JPanel`.

Comment: Oh ... i understand now.

Comment: @shmosel Just answered the question myself, in case someone else has the same problem and finds my answer. Hope i got everything correct ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @shmosel pointed out already, `T` might still be something other than `JPanel` which will lead to `JPanel` not satisfying `T`.

Here is an example of what one might do:

```
    val setup: JPanelExtendingClass.() -> Unit = {
        //Perform actions on splitpane
    }
    container(constraints = LC(), setup = setup)
```

This would lead to `T` being `JPanelExtendingClass` which `JPanel` doesn't conform to.

Therefore i ended up splitting the whole thing into two methods, one specifically for `JPanel`

```
fun panel(constraints: LC = LC(), setup: JPanel.() -> Unit): JPanel {
    return container(JPanel(), constraints, setup)
}
```

and another one for anything extending `JPanel`

```
fun <T : JPanel> container(containerComponent: T, constraints: LC = LC(), setup: T.() -> Unit): T {
    containerComponent.setup()
    containerComponent.layout = MigLayout(constraints)
    return containerComponent
}
```

this one does not define any default component though.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a function that can have any JPanel type as a parameter, and if one doesn't specify the parameter value, it will be JPanel.

Now suppose, you are calling the function in this way:

```
container<JPanelExtendingClass> { ... }
```

In this case, the type of the `containerComponent` parameter will be `JPanelExtendingClass`, and the value will be `JPanel()`.

`JPanel` is not a subclass of `JPanelExtendingClass`, so the compiler rejects it.

Here you don’t actually need that function to be generic, you can change the function to

```
fun container(containerComponent: JPanel = JPanel(), constraints: LC = LC(), setup: JPanel.() -> Unit): JPanel {...}
```

Comment: i need it to be generic in order to call subclass-specific functions on it

Comment: In that case, you can't have the default value for `containerComponent`; which you already have mentioned in your answer.

Comment: i am well aware of that, hence i already answered the question myself.